# Mongodb aggregate out of memory

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I'm using mongodb aggregate to sample documents from a large collection.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/

After making several consecutive calls, I see the memory of mongodb climbing up, and after around the 12th call, it crashes with OutOfMemory error.

How can I tell Mongodb to free up the memory after it has finished processing a query?

Comment: check out the fields index , or read the mongolog for COLSCAN information

Answer (score 1):

You should set `allowDiskUse` value to `true`. For example:

```
db.books.aggregate( [
           { $group : { _id : "$author", books: { $push: "$title" } } },
                      {allowDiskUse:true}
                  ] )
```

> Pipeline stages have a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. If a stage
>   exceeds this limit, MongoDB will produce an error. To allow for the
>   handling of large datasets, use the allowDiskUse option to enable
>   aggregation pipeline stages to write data to temporary files.

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are asking this is because you don't know how the [`$sample`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) operator works. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#behavior),

> In order to get N random documents:
>
> - If N is greater than or equal to 5% of the total documents in the collection, $sample performs a collection scan, performs a sort, and then select the top N documents. As such, the $sample stage is subject to the [sort memory restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-memory-limit).
> - If N is less than 5% of the total documents in the collection,
>         If using WiredTiger Storage Engine, $sample uses a pseudo-random cursor over the collection to sample N documents.
>         If using MMAPv1 Storage Engine, $sample uses the _id index to randomly select N documents.

So I think the number of random documents you want to get is greater than 5%. What you need is set `allowDiskUse` to `True`.

```
collection.aggregate(pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this, but it turns out the issue was the file system cache size, which is set to too large number by default.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out the issue was the storage engine cache. I'm using an EC2 instance, and it resulted in OOM error there. I've been able to solve it by assigning a smaller cache size like this:

```
mongod --dbpath /a/path/to/db --logpath /a/path/to/log --storageEngine wiredTiger --wiredTigerEngineConfigString="cache_size=200M" --fork
```